# Как отправить фото с ПК в беседу VK_API

Tags: python, python-3.x, vkontakte-api, вконтакте, vknet

Всем привет! Мне надо, чтобы бот отправлял фотку C ПК в беседу ВКонтакте.
Вот моя часть кода:

```
import vk_api
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import time
import requests


vk_session = vk_api.VkApi(token=TOKEN1) # Вход по токену.
vk = vk_session.get_api()
slovo = 'изменения' or 'изменение' or 'расписание'
url = 'https://vk.com/' + doc
if slovo in text:
    if ts > old_ts:
        print('-----------------')
        print('отправил сообщение')
        print('-----------------\n')
        arg = 'wall-'+new_owner+'_'+ts_id # получаем данный на последний пост
        webbrowser.open_new_tab(url)

        time.sleep(1)
        screen = pyautogui.screenshot('screenshot.png')
        pyautogui.screenshot('screenshot.png', region=(814, 300, 100, 200))
        template = pyautogui.locateOnScreen('screenshot.png')



       #vk.messages.send(chat_id='2',random_id = '',attachment = arg,message = '.') # отправляем от лица группы в ЛС

        time.sleep(8)
        os.remove('C:\\Users\\weil\\Desktop\\vk\\screenshot.png')
        print('successful')
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Рекомендую воспользоваться библиотекой **VkUpload**
В начале файла пишем

```
from vk_api import VkUpload
```

После строки `vk = vk_session.get_api()` пишем `vk_upload = VkUpload(vk)`
Так мы создали новую переменную для загрузки изображений.
В нужном нам месте кода(которое вы должны сами определить, если вы понимаете, что пишете), нужно написать:

```
with open('**название файла**', 'wb') as img_file:
    upload_image = upload.photo_messages(photos=img_file, peer_id=**номер чата+2000000000**)[0]
    pic = 'photo{}_{}'.format(upload_image['owner_id'], upload_image['id'])
```

В строке

```
#vk.messages.send(chat_id='2',random_id = '',attachment = arg,message = '.') # отправляем от лица группы в ЛС
```

`attachment = arg` меняем на `attachment = pic`

Comment: Спасибо за ответ, но выходит ошибка (NameError: name 'img' is not defined), не совсем догоняю на что можно заменить img

Comment: Заметил ошибку, сейчас исправлю.